# SELECTING a column from a previous latest record

Tags: mysql, html, sql, xhtml

Consider the following MySQL tables:

APPLICATIONS (contains all applications by all users)

```
unique_id |  user_id  |  date_of_application  |  date_ended  | score  |  status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            user_a          2010-09-09          2010-12-24     1.2      Ended
2            user_a          2011-03-03          2011-06-06     1.3      Ended
3            user_a          2011-08-08          2011-10-10     1.0      Ended

4            user_b          2010-09-09          2010-12-24     2.2      Ended
5            user_b          2011-03-03          2011-06-06     1.5      Ended

6            user_a          2012-01-01                                  Active
7            user_b          2012-01-02                                  Active
8            user_c          2012-01-03                                  Active
9            user_d          2012-01-04                                  Active
```

Desired result:

```
user_id  |  date_of_application  |  score  |  status
------------------------------------------------------
user_a          2011-01-01           1.0      Active
user_b          2011-01-02           1.5      Active

user_c          2011-01-03           10       Active
user_d          2011-01-04           10       Active
```

To explain; I want to select/display ALL records that has **status = 'Active'**. In addition, those users who are NOT first-time applicants (user_a and user_b) will have their score set to the **previous, latest** one (see the bolded parts in applications table) with **'Ended' status.** On the other hand, first-time users (user_c and user_d) will have their score set to 10.

Notes/to reiterate:

- Assume that score for 'Ended' applications/records will always be **positive** and **not null**
- **user_c** and **user_d** are **first time** applicants
- the **applications** table will have multiple records of the same users over time, **BUT** users can only have ONE 'Active' application/record at a time

I have the following to start with; this(or a query similar to this) gave me either NULL or 0 values for the score column

```
SELECT userid_, date_of_application, status,
score = 
(
     SELECT score 
     FROM applications
     WHERE status = 'Ended' AND 
           date_of_application = (SELECT MAX(date_of_application)
                                  FROM applications
                                  WHERE status='Ended')
)

FROM applications

WHERE 
status = 'Active'

ORDER BY 
score ASC,
date_of_application ASC
```

What am I missing here?
TIA.

Comment: Should the score be the lowest among the scores or the latest?

Comment: @Juniad Only the date (latest) is to be considered. The score can be of any value (highest or lowest).

Comment: I have answered on that basis. Just check whether it works fine for you or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you want the score to be on the basis of latest.
Try this -

```
SELECT apps.user_id, apps.date_of_application, apps.status,
       IFNULL(
              (SELECT app.score 
              FROM applications app
              WHERE  app.user_id = apps.user_id
              AND app.status = 'Ended' 
              ORDER BY app.date_ended DESC
              LIMIT 1), 10) AS score
FROM applications apps
WHERE  apps.status = 'Active'
ORDER BY apps.score ASC,
         apps.date_of_application ASC
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick responce. With a little tweaking, your answer does the intended task. Only thing that made me scratch my head is that the order of the scores behave strangely (its not in ascending nor descending) when I ran your code whilst leaving 'apps.' in the ORDER BY part. Taking it out though (leaving me with `ORDER BY score ASC, date_of_application ASC`) solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
SELECT user_id, date_of_application, status, coalesce(latest.score, 10) score
FROM applications
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT user_id, score 
   FROM applications a
   WHERE status = 'Ended' AND 
         date_of_application = (SELECT MAX(date_of_application)
                                FROM applications
                                WHERE status='Ended' AND user_id = a.user_id)) latest 
                                  ON latest.user_id = applications.user_id
WHERE status = 'Active'
ORDER BY date_of_application ASC
```